# How to get the object context menu

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I've been having issues getting the object context menu. I've tried the F9 key and right click but none is working. What can I do please?

Comment: if you've done a new action after creating your primitive you won't be able to have the operator box

Comment: Means I'll have to start again then?

Comment: do you really want the operator box (also called last operation box)? what do you want to change exactly? could you please show a screenshot?